# android Alarmmanager doesn't repeat over long intervals

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't get the alarm manager to trigger more than once when I setup an alarm doing the following:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderAlarmReceiver.class);
i.setData(Uri.parse(REMINDER_ID + getReminderID() + getTriggerAtTime()));
i.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, reminderID);
i.putExtra(DiaryListItem.DIARY_ID, parentDiaryID);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;, pi);
```

It seems to trigger the first day but doesn't trigger the next day.  The same thing happens when I try to make a weekly or monthly alarm.  Is there a better way of setting up long term alarms?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put that semicolon in your .setRepeating? I imagine your run would crash if it were actually still there:

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;, pi);
```

should be

```
mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

If that was just a typo, does your logcat give any kind of error?

Comment: Ya, sorry, that was just a typo. I haven't been using logcat to look at the errors yet because I've haven't yet gone in and set the system clock to 1 day ahead so the alarm will trigger in the emulator.